# Hide a button as soon as a web page is displayed in a browser (e.g. not embedded in an app) using Javascript

Tags: javascript, hide, microsoft-teams

I have a button on my page that opens the page in the default browser:

```
<button type="button" title="view full size in browser" onclick="NewTab()">
view in browser
</button>

<script>
function NewTab() {
            window.open(
            "https://mypage.aspx", "_blank");
        }
</script>
```

The button should only be displayed if the page is not yet shown in a browser, for example if it is [shown embedded in a Microsoft Teams page as a website tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0DSQl.png).

How can I detect if the page is displayed in a browser and then remove the button?

Answer (score 1):

There is no inbuilt function in teams. You have to manage this code manually.
If you use static tab/Configurable tab you need to add one parameter in manifest json content URL section like below:

```
"contentUrl": "<<your base url>>/Demo/?inTeams=true"
```

Add the below code in view file to detect if parameter is true it is inside the teams If false it is outside in teams.

```
 const url = new URL(window.location);

        const params = new URLSearchParams(url.search);

        if (params.get("inTeams")) {

            alert("inside teams"); 

          } else {

            alert("inside browser");

      }
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your approach. I'm not trying to do anything special within Teams, I'd like the HTML page to recognize whether it is displayed in a browser or not.